# Problem on quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\{x : x^{T}Ax \le 1\}$ is bounded if $A$ is positive definite, where $x^T=[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$  and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: If A is positive definite then the only thing we can be certain is that $x^{T}Ax>0$ for any non-zero x (according to the definition of pd matrixes). Can you provide further details on A and/or x? Maybe you are not reporting that it has a special structure.

Comment: This is all what given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question so I'm not going to completely answer it for you.  But I will give you 2 big hints:

1) Use the eigendecomposition of $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$ where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix containing the eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$.

2) The eigenvectors of $A$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, so you can represent $x$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $A$.  Namely $x = Qc$ for some vector $c$.

That should get you 80% of the way to the solution.